# Fetching svg element from node object in cytoscape.js

Tags: qtip, cytoscape-web

I want to show a tooltip (by using [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)) on node mouseover. In order to do this inside the

```
cy.nodes().bind("mouseover", function() { ... }
```

I need to bind the tooltip to a certain svg element. I cannot find a function on the node's public interface that would return the svg element to do this nor a way that I could directly add attributes to the individual node svg element during initialization. Cy certainly has this svg information stored in its _private. Of course I could find the svg element by calling node.position() and then searching the corresponding svg element, but is there a cleaner way to get it, straight from the node object interface?

Edit:  Atanas's suggestion works but I'm not sure whether it's a permanent solution. I want tooltip disabled on mouseout/zoom/pan/grab/select/.. which means I need to bind

```
$(".ui-tooltip").qtip('hide');
```

to those events on cy. I'd rather rely on qtip events and delays in displaying the tooltip. Now the tooltip seems a bit buggy since it's immediately hidden on these events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently did more or less the same thing - showing qtips on nodes - and it works.  Here is my code, hope it helps:

```
    cy.nodes().bind("mouseover", function(oEvent){
        var eid = this.data("id");

        $qtipDiv.css({
            "left": oEvent.clientX,
            "top": oEvent.clientY,
        });

        var menutext = "some text to be shown in tooltip";

        $qtipDiv.qtip({
            content: {
                text: menutext
            },
            show: {
                delay: 0,
                event: false,
                ready: true,
                effect: false
            },
            position: {
                viewport: true,
                adjust: {
                    method: "shift"
                }
            },
            style: {
                classes: "ui-tooltip-tipsy"
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: before this, I have `var $qtipDiv = $("#qtip-div");`

Comment: Strange. I now have two divs: #qtipDiv and #cy after it. When I try your test the tooltip is rendered after the #cy div, regardless of the x,y coordinates (ie same effect when leaving $qtipDiv.css command out).

Comment: Nevermind, it works by defining "target" in position as described in http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/position/. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cytoscape.JS was recently updated to use a HTML5 Canvas renderer for performance reasons. (This occurred approximately in August-Sept 2012)

Obtaining the event positions for node hovering is not completely implemented as of the current beta, but it does seem like a very important feature.

You can confirm the status of the implementation by typing this in the Javascript console:

```
cy.nodes().bind("mouseover", function(e) {console.log(e)})
```

This feature should be implemented very soon.